# Selenium can't be uninstalled

Tags: selenium, uninstallation

I installed selenium 4.4.3 but when I tried to find_elements(By.NAME, "") command it gave an error about the "By" command. I tried to uninstall selenium but even though I uninstall selenium, selenium4.4.3 still runs on my computer. I tried pip, pip3, conda uninstall selenium command on cmd but selenium is still in my computer. I want to uninstall this library and install the selenium 3.14 version. Can anyone help me?

Comment: First: what are you trying to achieve? Downgrading is rarely a solution. To avoid an XY Problem, explain clearly what is your goal, what url are you trying to scrape or test, and post what code you wrote and it doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @platipus_on_fire . I am trying to make a bot that looks for images from website1 and finds the same image from another website2. Here is an example url [link](https://www.tahtakaletoptanticaret.com/images/urunler/10-lu-simli-balik-firca-seti-7738.jpg) _italic_ **bold** . Using google lens is the process in my mind. Do you have better idea? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please share all your code including imports

Comment: `from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains`

Comment: PATH = "D:\Python Projects/chromedriver.exe"
wd = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
wd.get("https://www.tahtakaletoptanticaret.com/images/urunler/10-lu-simli-balik-firca-seti-7738.jpg")

` img = wd.find_element(By.XPATH,"/html/body/img")

action = ActionChains(wd)
action.context_click(img)`

Comment: [2668:14504:0903/090706.633:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:07:06.632] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Sisteme ba�l� bir ayg�t �al��m�yor. (0x1F)
[2668:14504:0903/090706.633:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [09:07:06.633] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Sisteme ba�l� bir ayg�t �al��m�yor. (0x1F)

Comment: I shared codes and errors I receive. Thank you for your help. @prophet

Comment: Do you really think it is readable in that way? all the relevant code and the errors should be included in the question itself